# How do I insert an object from a directory with wildcards?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").OLEObjects.Add filename:="C:\Users\myname\Desktop\" & fdcode & "*INVESTMENT INCOME DETAIL.pdf", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=150, Height:=10
```

fdcode is a variable of the fund code (go figure)

not letting me insert for some reason

Basically I have a bunch of fund codes with differing reports. For example:

```
FundA Investment Income Detail  
FundA Tax Summary

FundB Investment Income Detail  
FundB Tax Summary
```

The only issue is that between the FUND and REPORT NAME there can be some random characters.

I need to be able to put some sort of wild card that disregards what is in between.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to do, first explain what you want to do and then explain the problem/error. Wildcards in Excel/VBA are `*` and `?` and `#`

Comment: Why would you need a wildcard? Just use convert everything to UCASE and then evaluate with the INSTR command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the filename that you want to use:

```
Dim fName As String
fName = Dir("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\" & fdcode & "*INVESTMENT INCOME DETAIL.pdf")
```

That will set `fName` to the first file it finds in that directory which matches the specification you gave it.

Then use that filename (which won't include the directory name, so you need to continue specifying that) in your other code

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").OLEObjects.Add filename:="C:\Users\myname\Desktop\" & fName, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=40, Top:=40, Width:=150, Height:=10
```